# XSLT How to check if XML Node exists?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<Data>
  <Records>
    <Record>
     <AddInfo>
      <Info>
      </Info>
     </AddInfo>
    </Record>
  </Records>
</Data>
```

and XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Dane">
    <html>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="report.css"></link>
      <body>
        <h2>Table1</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th>XXX</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="XXX"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <h2>SecondTable</h2>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th>YYY</th>
            <th>ZZZ</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/AddInfo/Info">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="YYY"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ZZZ"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I want to make it like this: if node  exists, display table with "Info" nodes, and if not, display SOME TEXT.

I've been trying

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::AddInfo">
</xsl:if>
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="AddInfo">
</xsl:if>
```

But it is not working.

I want it like this:

```
Table1
---------------------
|     |      |      |
```

(condition: if inside XML will be  node, I want to display second table, under Table1)

```
SecondTable
-------------
|     |     |
```

How I can do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. One important thing, you've not posted your expected output. And, put all the scenarios in your input XML that you want to deal with.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where exactly do you want to insert this test? You only have one, general table, so "*if node exists, display table with "Info" nodes, and if not, display SOME TEXT*" makes very little sense.

Comment: So, you're telling that some text should be shown if the addInfo element is not present?

Comment: Yes, definetely i want it like Rnet said.

Comment: what is "if inside XML will be node" ? are you trying to say 'if some node exists do this'?

Comment: @vBB XSLT does not have if-else constructs, you need to use choose and write the 'else' condition in the default case of choose, as CoDEmanX has shown

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This outputs `Yep` if `<AddInfo>` exists as immediate child of `<Record>`, and `Nope` otherwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="AddInfo">Yep</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Nope</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you don't need `for-each`, you should let a second template match each `<Record>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="AddInfo">Yep</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>Nope</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also avoid `choose` and use two independent `if` conditions:

```
  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record">
    <xsl:if test="AddInfo">Yep</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(AddInfo)">Nope</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

If you don't want to limit it to immediate children, use `.//AddInfo` instead.

Consider the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Records/Record"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record">
    <table class="one"></table>
    <xsl:if test="AddInfo">
      <table class="two"></table>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs

```
<table class="one"></table>
```

if there's no `<AddInfo>` node in `<Record>`, and

```
<table class="one"></table>
<table class="two"></table>
```

otherwise.

You can solve this with neither using `if` nor `choose`. XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<Data>
  <AddInfo>
    <Info>This is ignored</Info>
  </AddInfo>
  <Records>
    <Record>
        <AddInfo>
          <Info>One,</Info>
          <Info>Two,</Info>
          <Info>Three</Info>
        </AddInfo>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Info>Ignored as well</Info>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Nested>
        <AddInfo>
          <Info>So is this</Info>
        </AddInfo>
      </Nested>
    </Record>
  </Records>
</Data>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Records/Record"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <table id="one"></table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AddInfo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record/AddInfo">
    <table id="two">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Info"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data/Records/Record/AddInfo/Info">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <Record>
    <table id="one" />
    <table id="two">One,Two,Three</table>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <table id="one" />
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <table id="one" />
  </Record>
</root>
```

Comment: Looks like I've been tested something like this, and it is not working, because, if there is no "AddInfo" node inside my generated XML, header of the SecondTable (YYY, ZZZ) is still displayed, instead of this header I would like to display SOME TEXT.

Comment: The condition node needs to wrap all nodes that generate the 2nd table of course. See my updated answer.

Comment: + 1 Good code. Just one minor note: If you know your input structure well, there is no need to type out the whole element hierarchy in template matches (e.g. `Data/Records/Record/AddInfo/Info`).

Comment: True, but it ensures that no equally called nodes are matched from other paths. Not sure if there's a difference in performance.

Comment: That's what I am saying. You would only need `Data/Records/Record/AddInfo/Info`, for example, if `Info` could appear as the child of elements other than `AddInfo`. No, there's no difference in performance. Otherwise, your code is exemplary.

Comment: I have a CMS collection (in Ektron) which has multiple smart forms. Each smart form is different and I am checking to see if a node does not exist/empty (if it exists) but it is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To check if node exist in xml this XSLT code works

```
<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="XMLNodeName">
                  <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s110">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NodeOne"/>
                    </Data>
                  </Cell>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <Cell`enter code here` ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s110">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NodeTwo"/>
                    </Data>
                  </Cell>
                </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```